# Fatal Error: Allowed memory size (ams) and out of memory (oom) on my PHP script

Tags: php, memory, memory-management, allocation

I always get this error:

```
Fatal Error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to allocate X bytes) and also
Fatal Error: Out of memory (allocated X bytes) (tried to allocate X bytes)
```

I'm so confuse because these days (4 days left) I can't handle it. I read some suggestion on stackoverflow but I still got same problem.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_trustmovie");
$init = ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
// global ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
// ini_get('memory_limit');
// memory_get_usage(true);

//--- FUNCTION **************
function getAllMatrikTrust() {
    global $conn;
    $mt = array();

    $rsrow = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from matrik_trust WHERE connect=1");
    $n = mysqli_num_rows($rsrow);

    if($n>0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rsrow)) {
            $mt[$row['row']][$row['column']] = 1;
        }
        return $mt;
    }
    return array();
}

function getAllInfoJarak() {
    global $conn;
    $mt = array();

    $rsrow = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from info_jarak");
    $n = mysqli_num_rows($rsrow);

    if($n>0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rsrow)) {
            $mt[$row['source']][$row['visited_node']] = $row['jarak'];
        }
        return $mt;
    }
    return array();
}

function getAllMatrikEstimatedTrust() {
    global $conn;
    $mt = array();

    $rsrow = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from matrik_estimatedtrust");
    $n = mysqli_num_rows($rsrow);

    if($n>0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rsrow)) {
            $mt[$row['row']][$row['column']] = $row['value'];
        }
        return $mt;
    }
    return array();
}

function getAllMatrikUserSimilarity() {
    global $conn;
    $mt = array();

    $rsrow = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from matrik_usersimilarity");
    $n = mysqli_num_rows($rsrow);

    if($n>0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rsrow)) {
            $mt[$row['row']][$row['column']] = $row['value'];
        }
        return $mt;
    }
    return array();
}

// ********************* FURTHER

function getMaxLevel($source) {
    global $arrAllInfoJarak;
    $mt = array();
    foreach($arrAllInfoJarak[$source] as $key => $value) {
        array_push($mt,$value);
    }
    return max($mt);
}

function getNodeByLevel($source,$jarak) {
    global $arrAllInfoJarak;
    $mt = array();

    foreach($arrAllInfoJarak as $source_key => $sourceuser) {
        foreach ($sourceuser as $vnode_key => $value){
            if($source_key==$source and $value==$jarak) {
                array_push($mt,$vnode_key);
            }
        }
    }
    return $mt;
}

function getUserSimilarity($row,$column) {
    global $arrAllMatrikUserSimilarity;

    foreach($arrAllMatrikUserSimilarity[$row] as $key => $value) {
        if($key==$column) {
            $sim = $value;
        }
    }

    if($sim) {
        return $sim;
    } else return 0;
}

function getEstimatedTrust($row,$column) {
    global $arrAllMatrikEstimatedTrust;

    foreach($arrAllMatrikEstimatedTrust[$row] as $key => $value) {
        if($key==$column) {
            $et = $value;
        }
    }

    if($et) {
        return $et;
    }  else return 0;
}


function getNodeParent($column) {
    global $arrAllMatrikTrust;
    global $init;
    $mt = array();

    // ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

    for($i=0;$i<300;$i++) {
        if(isset($arrAllMatrikTrust[$i][$column])) {
            foreach((array)$arrAllMatrikTrust[$i][$column] as $value) { //<<<--------- ERROR >>>
                array_push($mt,$i);     //<<<--------- ERROR >>>
            }
        }
    }   
    return $mt;
}

function calculatePathSim($column) {
    // ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    $nodeP= getNodeParent($column);
    $sumPS=0;
    if(count($nodeP)>0) { //ada parent
        foreach($nodeP as $p) {
            $value = getUserSimilarity($p,$column);
            if ($value) {
                if ($value > 0) {
                    $sumPS = $sumPS+($value*calculatePathSim($p));
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
    return $sumPS;
}

function calculateParentTrust($column,$source,$mTV) {
    $nodeP= getNodeParent($column);
    $sumPT = 0; 
    if(count($nodeP)>0) { 
        foreach($nodeP as $p) {
            if($mTV[$source][$p] != 0) {
                $value = getUserSimilarity($p,$column);
                if ($value) {
                    if ($value > 0) {
                        $nodepp = getNodeParent($p); //cek prent2
                        if (count($nodepp) > 0) {
                            foreach($nodepp as $pp) {
                                if(isPathTrust($pp,$source,$mTV)) {
                                    $sumPT = $sumPT + $mTV[$source][$p]; 
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            $sumPT = $sumPT + $mTV[$source][$p];
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
    return $sumPT;
}

function isPathTrust($column,$source,$mTV) {
    $isTrust = true;
    if ($mTV[$source][$column] == 0) {
        $isTrust = false;
    } else {
        $nodeP= getNodeParent($column);
        if(count($nodeP)>0) { //ada parent
            foreach($nodeP as $p) {
                $isTrust = $isTrust && isPathTrust($p,$source,$mTV);
            }
        }
    }
    return $isTrust;
}

// ===============================================
//                      MAIN 
// ================================================

//Inisialisasi **************
$arrAllMatrikTrust = array();
$arrAllInfoJarak = array();
$arrAllMatrikEstimatedTrust = array();
$arrAllMatrikUserSimilarity = array();

$arrAllMatrikTrust = getAllMatrikTrust();
$arrAllInfoJarak = getAllInfoJarak();
$arrAllMatrikEstimatedTrust = getAllMatrikEstimatedTrust();
$arrAllMatrikUserSimilarity = getAllMatrikUserSimilarity();

//***************************************
$mTV = array();
$uncheck = array();

//00000000000000
   $source= 28;
//00000000000000
$jarak=0;
$maxLevel = getMaxLevel($source);

for($i=0;$i<=$maxLevel;$i++) {
    $nodeL = getNodeByLevel($source,$i);
    foreach($nodeL as $node) {
        $sim = getUserSimilarity($source,$node);
        if ($sim) {
            if ($sim > 0) {
                $sumPS = calculatePathSim($node);
                $sumPT = calculateParentTrust($node,$source,$mTV);
                if ($sumPT > 0) {
                    $mTV[$source][$node] = $sumPS/$sumPT;
                } else {
                    $mTV[$source][$node] = 0;
                }
            } else {
                array_push($uncheck,$node);
                $mTV[$source][$node] = 0;
            }
        } else {
            array_push($uncheck,$node);
            $mTV[$source][$node] = 0; 
        }
    }
}

echo "After trust calculation = <br>";
print_r($mTV); 
echo "<br><br>";

foreach($uncheck as $node) {
    $mTV[$source][$node] = getEstimatedTrust($source,$node);
}

echo "After estimated_trust = <br>";
print_r($mTV); 
echo "<br><br>";


//insert db
foreach($mTV[$source] as $key => $value) {
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO trust_value VALUES ('$source','$key','$value')");
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

This are some changing that I've tried (change `php.ini` and set memory in script). This error come from `<<<--------- ERROR >>>` line (see code above).

```
When use 128M
134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes) 

256M
Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) 

512M
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes) 

1024M
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes) 

2048M
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1836318720) (tried to allocate 512 bytes

Unlimited
Out of memory (allocated 1836056576) (tried to allocate 35 bytes)
```

Is I get that error when I fetch array my data? well..there are 90000 row there. I used that code before with small data (only 10 row) and works perfectly. So I don't know how is going on.

Are all happen because I just use one variable to get that data (in the script) ? What should I put or add on them?

When that clear, I think I get same error in `calculatePathSim` function too..because it use `getNodeParent` function too. And also for all function after it.

My RAM 2GB. Is that means my RAM should be over 2GB? So, I've changed RAM to 4GB, but I still get that ams and oom. I'm newbie in there and also use native PHP. I don't know what I should do now.

I wish I get suggestion from you all. Need some advice. Thanks.

Comment: a quick suggestion before even reading your code. It's cause by you reading and holding too much data in memory, maybe you could try something like read 5000 rows -> process the first 5k rows -> read another 5k rows -> ....etc.

Comment: Ah..i wish i can. I don't know well.. Umm should i use variable to hold that each 5k data??? @JackyCheng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, the core output of you program is

```
echo "After trust calculation = <br>";
print_r($mTV); 
echo "<br><br>";

foreach($uncheck as $node) {
    $mTV[$source][$node] = getEstimatedTrust($source,$node);
}

echo "After estimated_trust = <br>";
print_r($mTV); 
echo "<br><br>";

//insert db
foreach($mTV[$source] as $key => $value) {
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO trust_value VALUES ('$source','$key','$value')");
}
```

maybe a restructure of you code would work. Most of the code below isn't valid, it's just a demostration of concept.

```
$query_row_count=5000;
while($query_row_count=5000){
    $query_row_count=<get 5000 rows from DB>
    <process them and make your arrays>
    foreach($mTV[$source] as $key => $value) {
        echo "Trust calculation = ".$value.', Estimated trust = ".getEstimatedTrust($value)."<br/>";
        mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO trust_value VALUES ('$source','$key','$value')");
    }
    <not a must, but your could clear those array here xxxarray=null e.t.c.>
}
```

you could have some sort of counter to record which row you're on so you could get the next 5k rows when it loops again

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by including a line at the top of the script

```
ini_set("memory_limit","12M");
```

The 12M sets the limit to 12 megabytes (12582912 bytes). If this does not work, keep increasing the memory limit.

Comment: what is the problem ..same problem ??

Comment: try adding php_value memory_limit 128M on php.ini